# Selection issue (list/multilist) codenameone

Tags: codenameone

i did the following to get the json values of the selected item of the list that displays in watchVideo form... but is there by any means i can get the values of next list items too so that i can set the next button in watchVideo form and directly play the next video too...

```
    findYoutubeMultiList(f).setModel(new com.codename1.ui.list.DefaultListModel(mData));
        findYoutubeMultiList(f).addActionListener((e) -> {
                    selection = (Map<String, String>) findYoutubeMultiList(f).getSelectedItem();
indexSelection = findYoutubeMultiList(f).getSelectedIndex();
**//i can get the index of selected item by above indexSelection but how to get the value of the incremented index??**
                    showForm("WatchVideo", null);
                });
```

Edited:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < response.size(); i++) {
                        Hashtable hm = (Hashtable) response.get(i);
                        Hashtable snippet = (Hashtable) hm.get("snippet");
                        HashMap<String, Object> m = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                        videoResource = (Hashtable) snippet.get("resourceId");
                        videoId = videoResource.get("videoId").toString();
                        m.put("video", videoId);
                        mData.add(m);
                    }
```

WatchVideo form:

```
protected void beforeWatchVideo(Form f) {

        for (int i = 0; i < mData.size(); i++) {
            //how to get the position of selection and more
 importantly how to get the values of incremented index
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through the source of your multilist and get the index of your selected item, then just increment the index and get the value at that index, decrease if you want to play the previous.

Remember to compare the index with 0 and source length to avoid NullPointer.

Comment: hello Diamond... i dont understand what you meant by source of multilist.. i have updated the question.. do u mean the portion i mentioned in edited part??

Comment: Make sure your mData is static and can be accessed on WatchVideo form. On WatchVideo, loop through mData and find the position  of **selection**. Now increment the position and set the value of selection to the new value and play.

Comment: i'm sorry diamond... can you be more precise?? yeah i can access mData from watchVideo form.
for (int i = 0; i < mData.size(); i++) {
            // how to get the position of selection and more importantly how to get the values of incremented index
        }

Comment: int idx = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < mData.size(); i++) {
            HashMap<String, String> m = mData.get(i);
            if ((m.get("video").equals(selection.get("video")))) {
                //increment for next
                if (i < mData.size() - 1) {
                    idx = i + 1;
                } else {
                    idx = mData.size();
                }
                //decrease for previous
                if (i > 0) {
                    idx = mData.size() - 1;
                }
            }
        }
        selection = mData.get(idx);